# Determine the value(s) of k for which p is a probability mass function

Tags: probability-distributions

> Determine the value(s) of k for which p is a probability mass function. Note that  n is a positive integer.
>   $$p(x) = kx, x = 1,2,3,... ,n$$

According to the solution manual, $k=\frac{2}{n(n+1)}$, but I don't know how to arrive at this answer. I know that because p is a probability mass function,
$$\sum_{x=1}^n kx=1$$
but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\begin{align*}
\sum_{x = 1}^n kx &= 1\\
k \left (  \sum_{x = 1}^n x \right )  &= 1\\
\end{align*}$

$\sum \limits_{x = 1}^n x = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ is one of the standard formulas for series.